# PNGJInputException when editing Metadata

Tags: java, android, png

I want to add some metadata to a png image. I am using android and the library PNGJ seems to be quite helpfull, yet I always get a "PngjInputException".

Here is the corresponding code snippet:

```
PngReader pngReader = new PngReader(file);
File destFile = new File(file.getAbsolutePath());
PngWriter pngWriter = new PngWriter(destFile, pngReader.imgInfo, true);
        pngWriter.copyChunksFrom(pngReader.getChunksList(), ChunkCopyBehaviour.COPY_ALL_SAFE);
        LinkedHashMap<String, byte[]> hashMap = bluetoothHelper.getHashMap();

for (String key : hashMap.keySet()) {
            pngWriter.getMetadata().setText(key, hashMap.get(key).toString());
}

for (int row = 0, c = 0; row < pngWriter.imgInfo.rows; row++) {
    IImageLine line = pngReader.readRow();
    pngWriter.writeRow(line);
}
pngReader.end();
pngWriter.end();
```

This is the Exception thrown:

> ar.com.hjg.pngj.PngjInputException: Failed to feed bytes (premature ending?)

Can anyone help me with this exception?

Answer (score 0):

You are writing to the same file you are reading. You should never do that. Change `destFile` to a different file and retry. (Warning: check first if the source png has not been corrupted after running the above code).